# Is there a performance cost if use multiple imports instead one named import

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I m wondering if there is a **performance cost** if we make **multiple imports**, like so:

```
import { wrapper } from './components/wrapper';
import { error } from './components/error';
import { products } from './components/products';
```

In each component folder i have an index.js and export it as named, like so:

```
export { default as wrapper } from '.wrapper';
```

---

**Compared to:**

Import all the files as named imports from the same source, like so:

```
import {
   wrapper,
   error,
   products,
 } from './components';
```

In `components` folder i have an index where i gather and export all the files, like so:

```
export { wrapper } from '...';
export { error } from '...';
export { products } from '...';
```

Comment: I do not know about performance, but I will do it when I end up having to repeat common imports on multiple files. Easier to change one place instead of 10+

Comment: It depends, are you bundling.   eg. Webpack etc, or are you using the browser's `import`?,  if your using the browsers `import` then using another file called `./components` would be another fetch to the server, so in theory could be slower.  I say theory, because using http2/spdy could actually negate that effect too.

Comment: why do you even care about performance?

Comment: @JonasWilms  Everybody should care about performance.  But I'm not sure that's what you meant, but rather "don't pre-optimise".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [ES262 specification](https://262.ecma-international.org/13.0/#sec-imports), `import` and `export` statements just provide information about dependencies between modules to the engine. *How* the modules are actually loaded in the end is *up to the engine* (there are a few constraints though). So whether there is actually a difference between importing from the source vs. importing a reexport depends on the environment.

Whatsoever the differences are probably irrelevant. Choose what works best for you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a fan of that approach. I like to split some components into folder and only expose what I want to the rest of my application. I really don't think that impact the perf on dev. (Obviously, there is absolutely no difference on prod as the whole project is pack in one file)

Comment: not necessarily true, decreasing bundle size can improve performance as explained here: https://twitter.com/iamakulov/status/1331551351214645251?lang=en

Comment: As a lot of person commented on his tweet, this should make no difference as there is no reason this could not be tree shaken. But the main question is about the difference of having multiple imports vs a single one, which I believe make absolutely no difference.